# Why does Unity give not detect enemies and run the TakeDamage() function after running the OverLapCircle() function? (UNITY 2D)[ANSWERED]

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mono

Here is the enemy health script with the TakeDamage() function

```
// Import the necessary Unity libraries.
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

// Define a public class named EnemyHealth that inherits from MonoBehaviour.
public class EnemyHealth : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Declare public float variable maxHealth and set its default value to 50.
    // This represents the maximum health of the enemy.
    public float maxHealth = 5;

    // Declare a private float variable currentHealth.
    // This represents the current health of the enemy.
    private float currentHealth;

    // Declare a public float variable knockbackForce and set its default value to 5.
    // This represents the force with which the enemy will be knocked back when damaged.
    public float knockbackForce = 5;

    // Declare a private Rigidbody2D variable rb.
    // This will hold a reference to the Rigidbody2D component of the enemy.
    private Rigidbody2D rb;

    // The Start method is called before the first frame update.
    private void Start() 
    {
        // Set the current health of the enemy to its maximum health at the start of the game.
        currentHealth = maxHealth;

        //assign the rb variable to be the Rigidbody2D component of the slime enemy
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Declare a public method TakeDamage that takes two parameters: an integer for the damage and a Transform for the player.
    public void TakeDamage(int damage, Transform player)
    {
        Debug.Log("ENEMY IS DAMAGED");

        // Reduce the current health of the enemy by the damage amount.
        currentHealth -= damage;

        // Check if the current health of the enemy has fallen to or below zero.
        if (currentHealth <= 0)
        {
            Debug.Log("Enemy has been killed"); //DEBUGGING
            // If the enemy's health is zero or less, destroy the enemy game object.
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
        Debug.Log("ENEMY IS KNOCKED BACK"); //DEBUGGING
        // Calculate the direction in which the enemy should be knocked back.
        // This is done by subtracting the player's position from the enemy's position to get the direction from the player to the enemy.
        // The result is then normalized to get a unit vector in the desired direction.
        Vector2 knockbackDirection = (rb.transform.position - player.position).normalized;

        // Apply a force to the enemy's Rigidbody2D in the direction calculated above.
        // The force is equal to the knockback direction multiplied by the knockback force.
        // The force is applied instantly, simulating the effect of an impulse (hence ForceMode2D.Impulse).
        rb.AddForce(knockbackDirection * knockbackForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
}
```

Here is the player combat script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerHitScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform attackPoint; // The point where the attack will originate.
    public LayerMask enemyLayers; // Layer to identify enemies.
    public SpriteRenderer playerSprite; // Reference to the player's SpriteRenderer.

    public float attackRange = 1f; // Range of the attack.
    public int attackDamage = 1; // Damage dealt by the attack.

    void Awake()
    {
        enemyLayers = LayerMask.GetMask("enemy");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame.
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            // Perform the attack.
            Attack();
            
        }

        // Flip attack point based on player's facing direction.
        if (playerSprite.flipX)
        {
            attackPoint.localPosition = new Vector3(-Mathf.Abs(attackPoint.localPosition.x), attackPoint.localPosition.y, attackPoint.localPosition.z);
        }
        else
        {
            attackPoint.localPosition = new Vector3(Mathf.Abs(attackPoint.localPosition.x), attackPoint.localPosition.y, attackPoint.localPosition.z);
        }
    }

    void Attack()
    {
        Debug.Log("Attack method starting"); //DEBUGGING
        // Detects all enemies within the attack range and stores them in an array.
        Collider2D[] hitEnemies = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(attackPoint.position, attackRange, enemyLayers);

        // For each enemy that was hit, call the TakeDamage method on their EnemyHealth script.
        foreach (Collider2D enemy in hitEnemies)
        {
            Debug.Log("An enemy(ies) has been damaged"); 
            enemy.GetComponent<EnemyHealth>().TakeDamage(attackDamage, transform);
        }
    }

    // This method is used to visualize the attack range in the Unity editor.
    void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
    {
        // If there is no attack point assigned, exit the method.
        if (attackPoint == null)
            return;

        // Draws a wireframe sphere at the attack point position with a radius equal to the attack range.
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(attackPoint.position, attackRange);
    }
}
```

I am using Unity version 2022.3.20f1.
My code editor is VSC.

I wanted the enemies detected from attackPoint in the OverLapCircle() function to be called to the TakeDamage function and decrease their health. I have tried assigning all variables correctly and I still am unable for the OverLapCircle to detect any enemies.

Comment: is your gizmo showing in the right place?  are you sure your enemies are in the enemy layer and not tagged enemy (as an example)

Comment: I have found the original bug, but I am encountering another error, the enemy will immediately be destroyed, instead of knocked back and have one hp taken. (Should I create a new post for this issue or continue this thread?) @BugFinder

Comment: @CreatoMan well does your code print "Debug.Log("Enemy has been killed");" when it's destroyed? if so it's probably an issue with the damage you are taking or the hp your character has, print them both.

Comment: I edited my code to have a cooldown before attacking in the Start() function of playerhitscript but now after the enemy is hit it will glide outwards without stopping. Is this due to the rb.AddForce function in TakeDamage() function of the EnemyHealth script? @DylanRobertson

Comment: @CreatoMan is there any friction to slow the object down? If you add a force & there is no friction / gravity then the object will keep it's velocity forever

Comment: Maybe you should change `Input.GetMouseButton(0)` -> `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)` to only handle a single click event instead of firing the attack **every frame** while the button stays pressed down in the first place ...

Comment: @derHugo this worked for me to solve the original error. Thanks for all the help any anyone who commented